# No Route matches on Form with nested atributes but not default action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form to update an item called post, but i need a different method than update because there are 2 ways to update the post, i have tried this in a lot of ways but i only get this error

No route matches "/topics/1/posts/35/completed"

the controller:

```
  def completed
    @post.download_remote_image
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to topic_path(@topic), :notice => t('.post_created') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

the view part:

```
= form_for [@topic, @post], :url => completed_topic_post_path(@topic, @post) do |f|
```

the routes:

```
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts do
        get 'complete', :as => :complete
        post 'completed', :as => :completed
    end
  end
```

Thanks !!

Comment: type rake routes and post the result you get

Comment: try:  to change :url => completed_topic_post_path(@topic, @post) to
:url => completed_topic_post_path(:topic_id=>@topic.id, :post_id=>@post.id)

Comment: also with your resource definition I get the following output from rake routes: topic_post_completed POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts/:post_id/completed(.:format) {:action=>"completed", :controller=>"posts"}

Answer (score 0):

:url => completed_topic_post_path(@topic, @post) needs to be :url => topic_post_completed_path(@topic, @post)

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was the magic of rails, using form_tag instead of form_for saves the day.